# How can I stop ARC releasing objects when I dont want it to?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Simple question: Can I stop ARC releasing objects when I dont want it to?

I am delcaring an object like so:

```
@property (strong) id myObject;
```

but the object still gets released. I have initialized the object. I have used the object. The object still gets released by ARC. I want to stop ARC doing this.

Comment: Please don't post duplicates.